# yahoo sites at ubuntu hang

Tags: cache, websites, yahoo

I have issues accessing yahoo sites, such as mail.yahoo.com om Ubuntu 22, with latest updates. Tested with latest Firefox (122, no ad-ons) and Opera. Some times pages load but most of the time the signal indicated page loading and nothing ever happens. For mail.yahoo.com, the login does not proceed to show the mailbox, when I get to enter the password. I have not noticed such issues with other web-sites. However, on different PC using Windows, using the same connection, everything works fine.
ufw is Active, and I have tried to remove cache and cookies (yahoo* only).
'nslookup mail.yahoo.com' does not report issues but seems to work.

How to solve this? Is this issue with *yahoo.com sites?

Comment: Please take a look in the Network tab of F12, and see what is showing errors or taking a long time.

Comment: Most of the time nothing appears after GET and e.g. www.yahoo.com site. Some times I get even to mailbox and I get message in mail-box screen: "you are offline". All other sites work, ans yahoo works on PC and Android at same time. Proxy disable in Ubuntu network-setting, and cache was empties.

Comment: Try using a user agent switcher extension and using the Firefox windows user agent string. If not, Chrome. Then look and see if you have any errors in Wireshark

Comment: Please advice where I find instruction & those programs.

Answer (score 0):

Partly solves:

> sudo apt install net-tools

> netstat -i

Check the 'Iface' name on the first row to get your

> sudo ip link set dev  mtu 1400

Some one wiser can explain details, and why the default settings had turned to something that needed to be corrected.
Issue occurred (and was solved) also on fresh install of Ubuntu 22, using latest Firefox and Chrome.

Still, after this, when reading mail for a while, mail.yahoo.com stops working, by not returning anything from *.yahoo.com (only on Ubuntu).